# Lighthouse "Ensure text remains visible during webfont load " for local files

Tags: fonts, seo, webfonts, lighthouse

I have 3 files that are being pointed out by the lighthouse.

These font files are located and hosted in our server, and this how it's being loaded in the head section.

```
<link rel="preload" href="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-base/resources/fonts/SlatePro-Bk.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="preload" href="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-libraries/resources/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="preload" href ="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-base/resources/fonts/SlatePro-Medium.woff"  as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

I added the `&display=swap` but it breaks the url and lighthouse does not recognize the URL

```
<link rel="preload" href="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-base/resources/fonts/SlatePro-Bk.woff&display=swap" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="preload" href="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-libraries/resources/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2&display=swap" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="preload" href ="/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-base/resources/fonts/SlatePro-Medium.woff&display=swap"  as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

How can I achieve to Ensure text remains visible during Webfont load for these 3 local files.
I also get 404 when adding &display=swap tho those urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`font-display: swap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display) to enable font-swapping.

This tells the browser to not block rendering while it waits for the font (well it gives it a short time to load the font and if it doesn't receive it in time will use a fall-back and swap it out when the font is available.).

You should also inline this CSS as it is [critical CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/)

The `&display=swap` part is a Google CDN parameter, it is not something built into the browser and so it needs removing. Also as you are serving from local you do not need `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

You also need to consider the [`woff2` format is not supported in Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/woff2) so you need a fallback for your font-awesome font.

### For clarity

You need to define the font using `@font` and add the `font-display: swap` property.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SlatePro-Bk';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(../etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-base/resources/fonts/SlatePro-Bk.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: so anywhere i have `@font-face{}` i need to add `font-display: swap;` ? currently in my style sheet i have this `@font-face` show up over 20 times, add it to each ? https://cssts.farmers.com/etc.clientlibs/farmers/clientlibs/clientlib-base.css

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, I have added it to the answer for clarity

Comment: can't access the file you linked but yes, any font should be swapped. If you have 20 fonts you have a bigger issue than just font swapping.

Comment: So it seems like its working now, lighthouse is not calling those links out anymore, but will this cause any issue for IE since font-display does not work?

Comment: No any CSS property that a browser does not recognised is just ignored. Like I said though you need an alternative for font-awesome as woff2 is not supported.

Comment: I have used font-display: swap but still the issue remains on google pagespeed insight. what could be the reason